# $ SO_{n+1} $ subgroup of $ U_n $

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

$ U_1 \cong SO_2(\mathbb{R}) $ are both the circle group. But for $ n \geq 2 $ is it true that $ U_n $ has no subgroup isomorphic to $ SO_{n+1}(\mathbb{R}) $?

Note that $ U_n $ is a compact $ n^2 $ dimensional group while $ SO_{n+1} $ is a compact
$$
\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$
dimensional group.

EDIT: Dietrich Burde provided a link to a closely related MO question which has a sumptuous buffet of answers provided by a Who's Who of the Lie theory crowd at MO. Highly recommend! The upshot of the simplest answer is that $ SO_{n+1} $ is not a subgroup of $ SU_n $ because the diagonal subgroup of $ SO_{n+1} $ is an elementary abelian two group of rank $ n $ but the largest elementary abelian two group in $ SU_n $ has rank $ n-1 $. This argument of course does not work for our case because $ U_n $ does contain a rank $ n $ elementary abelian $ 2 $ group (again just $ \pm 1 $ down the diagonal).

So the question is still open. In the meantime I'll look more carefully at the MO answers and maybe I can adapt one of the answers to apply in the $ U_n $ case.

Comment: For $SU(n)$ see [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408648/is-so4-a-subgroup-of-su3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no copy of $SO(n+1)$ in $U(n)$ for any $n\geq 2$.  To see this, assume not, so we have a copy $SO(n+1)\subseteq U(n)$.  Consider the determinant $\det|_{SO(n+1)}:SO(n+1)\rightarrow S^1$.

Since $SO(n+1)$ is connected, $\det(SO(n+1))$ must be a connected subgroup of $S^1$, so it is either trivial or all of $S^1$.  If it is trivial, then $\det$ is identically $1$ on $SO(n+1)$, which implies $SO(n+1)\subseteq SU(n)$, contradicting the linked MO question.

Thus, $\det(SO(n+1)) = S^1$.  It follows that the kernel $K = \ker \det|_{SO(n+1)}$ is a closed codimension one normal subgroup of $SO(n+1)$.  For $n\geq 2$ and $n\neq 3$, $SO(n+1)$ is simple of dimension at least $3$, so it has no codimension one normal subgroups.

This leaves the case $n=3$, where $SO(4)$ is not simple.  However, the only non-trivial normal subgroups have dimension $3$, so these are not codimension $1$ in $SO(4)$ (which has dimension $6$).

Comment: A small modification to this argument establishes the following:  If $H\subseteq U(n)$ is an embedded subgroup and the Lie algebra of $H$ has no abelian factors, then $H\subseteq SU(n)$.